# Python 3 update sqlite column by an amount specified in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, increment

Scenario: A quiz program with questions worth different amounts of points.

Sqlite database with a table Table1 with a field RunningTotal of type Int.

I'm looking to update the RunningTotal by the quantity 'updateby' passed to the function. This is a numerical value (but may be a string, so i'm converting it to integer to be sure.
tableid is used to identify which row to update.

eg (non-working code : error is that updateby is not a column name)

```
def UpdateRunningTotal(tableid,updateby)
   updateby = int(updateby)
   conn.execute("UPDATE Table1 RunningTotal=RunningTotal+updateby WHERE tableid=?", (tableid,))
```

I know if I put the following it works to increment the field by 1, but as a function i want more flexibility to increment by different amounts.

```
conn.execute("UPDATE Table1 RunningTotal=RunningTotal+1 WHERE tableid=?", (tableid,))
```

I'm trying to avoid doing a SELECT statement to read the current value of RunningTotal, do the math on that, and then use that result in the UPDATE statement...that seems inefficient to me (but may not be?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conn.execute("UPDATE Table1 set RunningTotal=RunningTotal+? WHERE tableid=?", (updateby, tableid,))
```

use this statement ... i have checked.. its working fine its updting the previous qnty present in database by RunningTotal+updateby

hope your issue will be resolved

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.